# Laravel horizon processing jobs but not visible

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I'm using Laravel forge and have setup Horizon for processing jobs.

The jobs are being processed I can see that in the forge logs. However, the jobs are not visible in my horizon dashboard. I can see that horizon is active, everything looks fine but they just don't show up.

[image]

[image]

My horizon config file is pretty basic:

```
'environments' => [
    'prod' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 20,
            'tries' => 1,
        ],
    ],

    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 3,
            'tries' => 1,
        ],
    ],
],
```

The jobs are being dispatched on the `default` queue.

When I look into my `failed_jobs` table I see records showing up, but not in my horizon dashboard!

What could be wrong here? I already have restarted server/horizon/nginx. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Possible reason is you are running `php artisan horizon` on terminal and at the same time workers are running.

Comment: I have the same issue. I have fpm, nginx, horizon and scheduler in different containers under the same network, all of them run the same code. The jobs are being processed, but the UI never gets updated reflecting that. Anybody has solved that?